# can we use OpenWRT as a router alternative

Tags: networking, open-source, hardware-virtualization

**Is it possible to convert old laptop with OpenWRT OS on it and 2 NIC as a routers alternative?**
and how that must be done?

Comment: OpenWRT is typically only compiled against ARM devices.  You would have to compile OpenWRT against x86 that includes providing the proper device drivers.

Comment: copy that, but I want to convert PC as a router instead of buying cisco routers for small network, and how can I do it ?

Comment: You would need to update, resolve all code conflicts, and build OpenWRT so it can successfully run on x86 hardware.  You would need to have a vast knowledge of the WiFi device in your machine.  You most likely would need to write your own Linux kernel drives since the only one that's that are compatible with OpenWRT are targeted towards ARM hardware.

Comment: Okay that's clear, but can u give me more description how to set it up? I never did that and want to do so.

Comment: Until you **recompile** OpenWRT to work on x86 hardware there is no way to setup OpenWRT on your laptop.  There are better solution that exists for x86 hardware than OpenWRT.  Honestly, unless you have a working build, there isn't much to provide.  How you go about building OpenWRT to work with x86 is a very complicated process, a process that is not impossible, but certainly very difficult for one single person.

Comment: honestly laptop hardware is x64 not x86

Comment: **All Intel/AMD x64 hardware is x86 hardware.**  x64 is an extension of x86 architecture.

Comment: shortly, you say that: better to buy Cisco router for small network instead of setting up through OpenWRT ?

Comment: **I never said "it's better to buy a Cisco router"**  What I said was, there are existing solutions for x86 hardware that exist, but OpenWRT isn't one of those solutions.  I never once used the word "Cisco" in any of my commentary.  If it will avoid additional discussions, [pfsense](https://www.pfsense.org/download/), is probably what you are looking for.  Note: `AMD64` is compatible with all Intel/AMD 64-bit processors.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your help. I think you right pfsense is better for what I need. If you have more clarification how to set it up I'll be glad to read it

Comment: You should read the instructions on the website.  It has everything you need to be sucessful.

Comment: And it's **a lot easier** to just use some existing small Linux distro on your Laptop, and turn it into a router in this way instead of using OpenWRT.

Comment: It is entirely practical to turn an x86 box into a router using, for example, Linux. Ive been doing it for 20+ years.  dd-wrt is, at its core, a linux distro designed for embedded boxes but uses the same architecture.  If you dont have the knowhow to do it on with Ubunto or a Redhat or Slackware variant there are router distros. I know of Zeroshell,  ut that look eol. PFSense may be useful to you (although that is BSD)

Comment: @dirkt more description  please. and yeah how to set two NIC at the same time ? Imagine you have an public IP address from your ISP and you want to make a NAT for local small network (near 50 endpoints)

Comment: There are many resources on the net that tell you how to install solution X or Y from scratch that may fit your needs. Try attempting some of them and return with specific questions of problems that arise during your attempts. No one's going to magic up a tailor made how-to for you based on the tiny bit of information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

> how to set two NIC at the same time?

See end of the answer for the script I use on my old desktop with Devuan (Debian variant without systemd) to temporarily NAT my LAN (eth0) to my home router on the WLAN (wlan0). This will work with any NICs.

It includes firewall rules so only connections initiated from the LAN will pass. You need additional rules for port forwarding.

I have also configured a DHCP server on `eth0`. In your case

> for local small network (near 50 endpoints)

I'd use `dnsmasq` as a lightweight one-stop implementation of DNS proxy with caching, DNS for the LAN, and DHCP. (That's also what many routers use, BTW).

And google a bit for more information, there must a hundred tutorials on how to set up NAT on Linux (I learned this from one of the decades ago). I also posted this script at least three times on stackoverflow.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                  

# masquerade $1 (e.g. eth0, ppp0) as $2 (default wlan0)                                                                                                                                      

INTIF="$1"
EXTIF=${2:-wlan0}

echo $INTIF $EXTIF

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

This script clears the firewall when run, something you may or may not want.

There are various ways to make this setup "permanent" (restored on boot). Details depend on the distro you use.

Comment: thanks for your answer